# PyQt4: Window shows up at another position after hide() and show()

Tags: python, window, pyqt, positioning

Using PyQt4, when I hide a window and show it afterwards, it appears at another position (at least here on Linux). Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication([])
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)

def hideShow():
    widget.hide()
    widget.show()

widget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton('Hide/Show', clicked = hideShow))
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

The window disappears and appears, but a bit below and to the right of the original position. I think it's displaced by the size of the window manager's frame around the actual widget.

How can I place the window at the exact position where it was? And why does it move at all? Shouldn't it stay where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, window placement can be very unpredictable. See [this section](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#x11-peculiarities) in the Qt documentation for a break-down of the issues.

There's probably no general solution to the problem, but for me, setting the geometry *before* the initial `show()` seems to work:

```
...
widget.setGeometry(200, 200, 100, 50)
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

**UPDATE**

After some testing with the KDE window manager, I may have discovered a potential solution.

It seems that calling `show()` immediately after `hide()` does not give the window manager enough time to calculate the correct window position. So a simple workaround is to explicitly set the geometry after a small delay:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer

app = QApplication([])
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)

def hideShow():
    widget.hide()
    QTimer.singleShot(25, showWidget)

def showWidget():
    widget.setGeometry(widget.geometry())
    widget.show()

widget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton('Hide/Show', clicked = hideShow))
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

This works for me using KDE-4.8 and OpenBox, but of course YMMV.

Comment: Well, then I think one can't solve this problem, as setting the geometry before the initial show() will only help when hiding and showing the window is done from that position and the window hasn't been moved.

Comment: @TobiasLeupold. For me, moving the window between clicks of the "Hide/Show" button doesn't make any difference (i.e. the position stays constant). If I comment out the `setGeometry` line, the window jumps up and to the left on the *first* click, but then remains constant. This is using the OpenBox window manager. What window manager are you using?

Comment: I use KDE 4.8.5 on Gentoo Linux.

Comment: Adding a small delay like you did makes the window actually appear at the very same position – but interestingly, when I move the window to another position before hiding and re-showing it, it does not appear at the position where it was before, but at the original position where it was placed when started initially … adding a pos = widget.geometry() and a widget.setGeometry(pos), the window appears at the same position, but only for the first time – then it's dislocated like before.

Comment: @TobiasLeupold. Looks like the position needs to be set explicitly before re-showing the window (see my updated answer).

Comment: Adding widget.setGeometry(widget.geometry()) before the show() also preserves the widget's size when it has been changed before. Thanks a lot, that's it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem with xfce. Perhaps you could get the position before hiding it (or when displaying it, depending on what you want), store it away, and then set it when it is displayed again with setGeometry()? A bit hacky perhaps..

Comment: I tried both pos = widget.geometry() and pos = widget.frameGeometry() before the hide() and widget.setGeometry(pos) with no effect. The window appears at the very same displaced position.